# Automatically Scaling Canvas to drawn image

Tags: html, canvas, size, scale, drawimage

I am drawing an image to a canvas using the following javascript.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');

img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
}

img.src = "images/testimg.jpg";
```

When I do this I only see a portion of the original image. Can anyone explain how to draw the entire original image on the canvas, preferably without specifying the dimensions of the original photo.

Answer (score 0):

Set the canvas height and width to that of the image.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasId');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = document.createElement('IMG');


    canvas.height = ImgHeight;
    canvas.width = ImgWidth;


img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,imgWidth,imgHeight);
}

img.src = "images/testimg.jpg";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate to @Ctrl Alt Design's answer which resizes the canvas to fit the image.

This example scales the image to fit the canvas while maintaining the image's aspect ratio:

```
var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="images/testimg.jpg";
function start(){

    // calculate the scaling factor necessary
    // to fit the image in the exsiting canvas size
    // while maintaining the image's aspect ratio

    var scaleFactor=Math.min((canvas.width/img.width),(canvas.height/img.height));

    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width*scaleFactor,img.height*scaleFactor);

}
```